# want some information about inserting through join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I know how to update the table using `join` like:

```
update t1
    set t1.id=t2.id2
from #table1 t1
inner join #table2 t2
    on t1.id=t2.id2
```

But I don't know about the inserting.
How can I insert the data from `#table1(id,name)` 
to #`table2 (id,name)` using `join`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be You are looking like this :

```
insert into  #table2 (id,name) 
select  #table1 t1.id,t1.name
from #table1 t1
        inner join #table2 t2
        on t1.id=t2.id2
```

Comment: ok ok, can i insert one particular record to other table to map with particular id?

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table2(id, name)
SELECT t1.id, t1.name FROM table1 t1
 INNER JOIN table2 t2
 ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: :what if i want to insert just a name for particular id ?

Comment: @nishantnandgaonkar just add a where clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into  #table2(id,name) 

select  #table1 t1.id,t1.name

from #table1 t1

        inner join #table2 t2

        on t1.id=t2.id2
```

Comment: :what if i want to insert just a name for particular id ?

Comment: THEN USE insert into #table2(name ) select t1.name...... OR insert into #table2(id) select #table1 t1.id –